# Select from a different database on the same server in Postgres 9.6?

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I'm using a different database, on the same postgres Windows server from the one I'm querying from, I've tried the following, but I believe that maybe I'm doing it wrong:

```
SELECT *
    FROM dblink('dbname=Archives', 
    'SELECT "BeverageOrderId", "AccountNumber", "BeverageId", "BeverageString", "CardLevelId", "LocationAddressPartId", "MenuId", "PatronName", "ServiceLocationAddressPartId", "TotalPrice", "SpecialInstructions" FROM public."BeverageOrders" WHERE "AccountNumber" IN (''YYYY'', ''XXXX'')')
```

I also discovered that I likely don't have have the `dblink` extension installed and every place I've read about that, they're using Linux and not Windows.

However my other database resides on the same server, so I'm not even sure that I need to be using `dblink`.

Comment: dblink is an [extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib.html) which needs to be installed using [create extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html)  but why don't you use multiple schemas instead? That will be a lot easier to deal with

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's because the schema is not mine to toy with.  There's a public schema for both DBs.  It actually all looks very default.

Comment: Nevertheless: needing cross-database queries is often a sign of mis-using databases as namespaces. If you need to do that very often you might also want to consider using foreign tables

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not the one setting it up, but I am the one querying it.  The DBs are setup so that their table definitions are exactly the same, but every so often a script runs that pulls data from the production one to the archive one to keep the production one fast.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well I mean I guess I can set my own schema up with everything in it for one of the two DBs.